# Can a non-dimensionless physical quantity ever be continuously exponentiated?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units, rotation, clifford-algebra

I was really surprised and somewhat skeptical when I first learned that you can exponentiate complex numbers and matrices and such.  But then it makes sense once you consider (natural) exponentiation as defined by the differential relation

$$dy = y\ dx$$

That is, as long as $x$ and $y$ are elements of the same continuous ring, you can keep grabbing an infinitesimal "fraction" $y\ dx$ of $y$ and adding it to itself, until the $dx$'s add up to $x$.

But obviously, if $x$ has physical units, then $y\ dx$ doesn't have the same units as $y$, so you can't add the two.  But I was just wondering if there could ever be a context where it could be useful to imagine "closing the physical algebra" so that you *can* add quantities with different physical units.

(And notice that the result *would* still be invariant with respect to choice of unit system!)

This question is inspired by geometric algebra, in which you can add elements of different grades.  You get multivectors, which at first glance don't appear to have any meaning, but then you find out they can actually represent transformations such as rotors.  And exponentiation has interesting interpretations; for example, exponentiating the bivectors gives you the rotations (rotors).

Comment: This seems a bit misguided -- we _do_ exponentiate physical quantities all the time. It's just that we divide the units out first. Have you seen $e^{-iHt/\hbar}$ in quantum mechanics?

Comment: @knzhou  Point taken, I've edited the title accordingly.

Comment: I'm not really seeing your point about $dy = y \,dx$.  What does this have to do with taking $e^y$ or $e^x$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Exponentials and logarithms, as well as arguments of functions like sine and cosines, work fine with non dimensional quantities, so that you can re-write you condition about exponentials (that in general has no sense for dimensional quantities) as

$d \left( \dfrac{y}{y_0} \right)= \dfrac{y}{y_0} d\left(\dfrac{x}{x_0}\right) $.

You can easily realize that we could only introduce the non-dimensionalization of $x$ to get an expression with the right physical units.

While this process gives you the right results for exponentials and other functions that need non-dimensional arguments, I'd not sum non dimensional expression of quantities with different physical units before I'm sure that the operation is meaningful.